# How to specify variable number of arguments using jni

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, multiple-arguments

I have a method in c that is:

```
static int          callLuaFunctionWithParams(const char *functionName, int numParams, ...);
```

So it contains a variable number of arguments, and I want to export it so that it could be used on the android app.
On the JNIBindings I'm exporting it like:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_callLuaFunctionWithParams(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring functionName, jint numParams, ...);
```

but how can I specify that syntax on java

```
public native void callLuaFunctionWithParams(String functionName, int numParams, ????);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Java requires varargs all to be of the same base type. You could specify `Object...varargs`, but then any conversion required is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```
public native void callLuaFunctionWithParams(String functionName, int numParams, Object... params);
```